# How to reorder data in a tree stored using the nested set model?

Tags: php, mysql, model, nested, set

I have a table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `nested_set`
(
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `lft` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_parent` int(11) NULL,
    `Name` varchar(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk_nested_sets` (`id_parent`)
)
```

I want to preserve level structure but to reorder alphabetically nodes within each node.
How can i achieve this using MySQL or (PHP and MySQL)?

(id_parent is added to the model so i can easy move nodes up or down)

Comment: This looks like a binary tree?  If that is the case, preserving structure would either be pointless - as each will have the two nodes, or tedious the further down you go and having hundreds of nodes all with different parents. (also, what have you attempted to do in order to alphabetize them?)

Comment: No it's not a binary tree (each nodes can have unlimited subordinate children). I haven't done anything in order to alphabetize them. I can successfully move single nodes within given node - up, down, top, bottom, but when it comes to reorder everything at once i'm stuck.

Comment: What is `lft` and `rgt` for then?  A typical tree only has a node with the id of the parent and other information pertaining to that node - though `lft` and `rgt` seem to be `id` identifiers.

Comment: `lft` and `rgt` are explained here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) and here [link](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: Ahh, ok. I haven't dealt much with those as I never liked the expense of adding/modifying the table. (And I apologize for previous comments, I missed the `nested set` in the title as most questions don't have good titles to go with their question - I got in the bad habit of just basing everything off the content of the question. ^^)